# Select records from one table and sort the result using a column from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on payroll system for the CRM located at my work and I'm trying to save having to store redundant data which over a period of years will stack up.

I tried to relate it to "[how to get value from mysql table ordered by another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618717/how-to-get-value-from-mysql-table-ordered-by-another-table)" but had no luck.

I have a `Users` table

```
===========================================
# id | username | first_name | last_name  #
===========================================
# 1  |   joe    |    Joe     |    Blow    #
===========================================
```

I also have a `Timesheets` table which stores the data of each individual session which for the sake of keeping short I have condensed a little in this question and obviously misses the full date/time in start and finish.

```
============================================
# id | username |    start   |   finish    #
============================================
# 1  |   joe    |   00:00    |    23:59    #
============================================
```

What I want to achieve is to order the results from the `Timesheets` table by the `last_name` column in the `Users` table with just the username that is derived the `Timesheets` table.

What I am trying to attempt here:

```
SELECT * FROM `Timesheets` WHERE `start` >= '{$monday}' AND `finish` <= '{$sunday}' ORDER BY (`Users`.`last_name` WHERE `username` = `Timesheets`.`username`)  ASC
```

MySQL is clearly not my niche, what query would provide the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use a `JOIN` and then `ORDER BY`, like this:

```
SELECT ts.*
FROM timesheets ts
JOIN users
ON ts.username = users.username
ORDER BY users.last_name
```

You may add the `WHERE` clause as required before the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Timesheets T
JOIN Users U ON T.username = U.username
WHERE T.start >= '{$monday}' AND `finish` <= '{$sunday}'
ORDER BY U.last_name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

use join for this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM timesheets t
JOIN users
ON t.username = users.username  WHERE t.start >= '{$monday}' AND t.finish <= '{$sunday}'
ORDER BY users.last_name
```